# integral of a product of sine function with a polynomial

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

What is the integral of this function :

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^{\alpha} \sin{ax} \, \mathrm{d}x$$ with $\alpha, a$:real values?

Comment: Let me WolframAlpha it for you: [link](http://tinyurl.com/q85nkm2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a compact closed. We split the integral as

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{0}x^\alpha \sin(ax)dx + \int_{0}^{\infty}x^\alpha \sin(ax)dx \longrightarrow (*). $$

> $$ \implies I = (1+(-1)^{\alpha+1}){a}^{-\alpha-1}\Gamma  \left( \alpha+1 \right) \sin \left( \frac{\pi \,
>  \left( \alpha+1 \right)}{2}  \right) .$$

To get the above answer follow the steps

1) make the change of variables $t=-x$ for the first integral in $(*)$,

2) use the [Mellin transform tables](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html) since the integral

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha} \sin(ax ) dx$$

is nothing but the Mellin transform of $\sin(a x)$

> $$ F(s)= \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1} \sin(ax)dx\,\quad -1<Re(s)< 1 .$$

with $s=\alpha +1$.

**Note:** I tried Maple 17 and wolfram alpha no response. However they give closed form answers for special cases. For instance $\alpha=-1/2$.

Comment: and if we have a cosine in the place of a sine function? I mean $\cos(ax)$

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: Just see what's the Mellin transform of $\cos(x)$.

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal thank you for your help :)

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: You are welcome.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: Pay attention to what of values of $\alpha$ the integral converges. See what I added.