# integral research solution (mellin transform)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

what is the result of this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^{-5/3} \cos \left[ \left(x-1 \right)\times h\right] \, \mathrm{d}x$$
with : h a constant.
Thank you.

Comment: Is't a Principal Value ?. Isn't ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the identity

$$ \cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b) $$

then proceed just like in the [previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891468/integral-of-a-product-of-sine-function-with-a-polynomial).

**Added:** The approach which I gave you is correct. However you are now asking a different question. You are looking for a real value which Robert gave you an answer and we thank him for doing that. Let me answer it in a more general setting.

Your integral is a special case of the more general integral

$$I(\alpha) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{\alpha} \cos((x-1)h) dx $$ $$
= \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha} \cos((x-1)h) dx  + (-1)^\alpha\int_{0}^{\infty}x^\alpha \cos((x+1)h) dx $$
 which is a multivalued function in general. In your case $\alpha = -\frac{5}{3}$ which causes the $(-1)^{-5/3}=(-1)^{1/3}$ (see complex variables) to have multi-values. If you are interested in a real value of the integral you can choose the right value which is in this case $-1$. So choosing the root $-1$ which gives you the answer

$$ I(-5/3) = \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-5/3} \cos((x-1)h) dx  + (-1)\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-5/3} \cos((x+1)h) dx $$

$$ I(-5/3) = {\frac {3\pi \,{h}^{2/3} }{\Gamma  \left( 2/3\right) }}\sin (h)$$

which agrees with Robert's answer.

**Note:**

1) The roots of $z^3+1$ are

> $$ -1,\, \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

2) You can do the same with the formula I gave you in the previous problem to get a real value of the integral.

Comment: Yes, but I have found that the solution is complex and It seems weird for me. The result diverge.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: The integral does not diverge! Howevr you get a complex number as a result.

Comment: The integral does diverge at $0$, but you can use a Cauchy principal value **if** you take the real $x^{-5/3}$ for $x < 0$, and then you will get a real result.

Comment: @ Robert Israel This is what I have found, that the function takes great values as h tends to infinity. And in my case it must be zero as h tends to infinity, because it is an autocorrelation function of a Von Karman spectrum.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Effectively I get a complex resut, and the result tends to infinity aas h tends to infinity. This is not what I found about the autocorrelation function of a Von karman spectrum.

Comment: @AhmedAbrous: I'll be with you later.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Of course the integrand behaves as $\frac{c}{x^{5/3}}$ near zero and we need to consider the principal value. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Is there any other solution to verify the result of the integral, for ex. transform the integral to the sum and get the result after?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal A problem with this type of question is: The integral conditions must be set at the very beginning and "maybe possible" what branch cut we are using for $z^{-5/3}$. Otherwise we start to guess or/and any user can decide what to do. For example: you like a real value or a complex value, etc...

Comment: @FelixMarin: You are right. We can not guess what they want. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real answer, you want to use the real cube root of $x$ when $x < 0$.
This is also needed to cancel the divergence of the integral at $0$ (using a Cauchy singular value).  So write the integral as

$$\eqalign{ &\int_0^\infty  x^{-5/3} \left(\cos(h (x-1)) - \cos(h (-x-1))\right)\; dx\cr 
&= 2 \sin(h) \int_0^\infty  x^{-5/3} \sin(hx)\; dx\cr
&= 2 h^{2/3} \sin(h) \int_0^\infty t^{-5/3} \sin(t)\; dt\cr
&= \dfrac{3\pi}{\Gamma(2/3)} h^{2/3} \sin(h) }$$

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal Thank you very well, wow the solution is well explained and objective.

Comment: It means $\left(-x\right)^{-5/3} = -x^{-5/3}$. It's with $\left(-1\right)^{-5/3} = \left[\left(-1\right)^{1/3}\right]^{-5}=\left(\color{#c00000}{\LARGE -1}\right)^{-5}$.